# Базовый путь на сайте. Проблема с ЧПУ

Tags: .htaccess, html

Приветствую. Подскажите

```
//.htaccess
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?myget=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Делаем так, далее на сайте пропадают все картинки:

```
// вот так
mysite.ru/test/
// /img/logo.jpg - ищется как mysite.ru/test/img/logo.jpg (что есть неправильно)
// картинка реально в mysite.ru/img/logo.jpg
```

Гуглил, искал - глухо. Варианта 2:

1. Указать абсолютные адреса (что можно, но полно сайтов без этого обходятся)
2. Указать как то директорию от которой смотреть все адреса (базовую так сказать)

Вопрос: Подскажите, можно ли как то указать этот самый базовый путь, для всех файлов JS/CSS, что бы не было глюков с адресами? И где это прописывается?

p.s. исправил 1 ошибку

Comment: Попробуйте так:  

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Comment: написал. теперь сайт при mysite.ru/test/ - перебрасывает на родительный каталог. Как быть?

Comment: А если так?  

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?myget=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: нет, к сожалению. Что же, придется установить какую ни будь CMS и расковырять ее до основания. Там тоже применяются аналогичные адреса и работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При адрессации на картинку нужно ставить слеш, чтобы указать, что читать от корня. К примеру:

```
<img src="/img/logo.png" />
```

Раз вы говорите, что с mysite.ru заходит нормально, значит проблема именно в этом.
Или же попробуйте:

```
<img src="../img/logo.png" />
```

Если проблема остаётся, то видимо сервер не правильно настроен, нужно обратиться к хостеру.

Comment: ммм.. указал картинку с первым слешем - картинки нет.

извиняюсь, с mysite.ru - оказывается браузер картинку из кэша тянул. нет ее там

Comment: мм, значит проблема не в этом. Пока разбираетесь - напишите всё-таки хостеру, если это конечно не ваш сервер =) Лишним не будет. Потому что должно всё работать со слешом впереди

Comment: сейчас все заработало на mysite.ru. на mysite.ru/test/ - переадресация в корень. т.е. решилась 1 проблема, появилась другая

Comment: Странно, этого не должно быть. Попробуйте RewriteRule (.*)/$ index.php?myget=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: попробуй поменять index.php на index2.php. Посмотрим, может быть он просто myget не передаёт

Comment: при (.*)/$ index.php?myget=$1 [L,QSA] и при (.*)/$ index2.php?myget=$1 [L,QSA] - т.е. с вот этой новой регуляркой переадресации нет, просто страницы нет. Может у кого есть своя работающая конструкция? Вроде там пару строчек..

Comment: Т.е. преобразование идёт на index2.php? Просто например у меня всё работает, дело в конфигах сервака.